# Two Intents in one activity

Tags: android

Problem is that i am sending one intent from add note class and then return intent from third activity with a value and get it in addnote class but it crashes with null point exception

```
public class AddNote extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);

        String vstr=getIntent().getExtras().getString("R");
        int v=Integer.parseInt(vstr);

        if (v == 0){
            EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            editText.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

    public void Option(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),list.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

public class Color_view extends AppCompatActivity
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_color_view);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (position==0){

                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),AddNote.class);
                    intent.putExtra("R", 0);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
        movie_titles2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.movie_titles2);

        int i = 0 ;
        adaptor = new colorAdaptor(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.font_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(adaptor);
        for (String titles: movie_titles2){
            colorProvider listDataProvider2 = new colorProvider(movie_poster_resource[i],titles);
            adaptor.add(listDataProvider2);
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your error message give which line it is failing?

Comment: it was on getintent value that was null ; now its clear with 

intent i = new intent(this.class)
i.putextra("int",0)


& on reciving

int a = getintent().getintextra("int",-1);

thanks for quick responding